# how to scrape interactive line charts with scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the viewers chart at https://twitchtracker.com/games/32982. I tried to inspect the page, but I can't seem to find the values of the chart.

[image]

I tried to inspect element, but all I get is this.

Comment: This question is missing basic debugging details: what exactly have you tried, where is your code attempts?

Comment: Looks like the data is embedded in under `stats-chart` you will have to open some of the elements and check. If you want the chart, it's likely you will have to scrape the data, and build the chart yourself.

Comment: @DollarTune-bill, yes but how to I scrape the data? The tags `path` and `fill` don't have the exact values

Comment: @Prophet I tried with Selenium, requests and beautiful soup but I don't know how to get the data on the charts as it is using Highcharts

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might go about extracting the data you need with scrapy-playwright:

```
import scrapy

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.twitch.tv',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'authorization': 'Bearer a4xqvkgns8duyuudnnr3pmo5mjxl36',
    'client-id': '2eji4dzts0ppwwpprxwnao9d27sfwz',
    'origin': 'https://twitchtracker.com',
    'referer': 'https://twitchtracker.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}


class twitchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'twitch'
    start_urls = ['https://twitchtracker.com/games/32982']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                headers=headers,
                callback = self.parse,
                meta = {
                    'playwright':True
                }
            )
    def parse(self,response):
        from collections import defaultdict
        values = response.xpath("(.//*[name()='g'][@class='highcharts-series-group'])[1]//*[name()='g']//*//@d").getall()
        class_values = response.xpath("(.//*[name()='g'][@class='highcharts-series-group'])[1]//*[name()='g']//*//@class").getall()
        chart_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for charts, names in zip(values, class_values):
            #chart_dict[names].append(charts)
            chart_dict['big'].append(charts.split(' ')[1::3])
            chart_dict['small'].append(charts.split(' ')[2::3])
            chart_dict['classes'].append(names)

        yield chart_dict
```

This grabs the chart data for the different series of graph as we get overlapping line graphs.

Then we extract for the two values represented by either `big` or `small`, the rest you can do with plotting the correct values.

Comment: I have windows so playwright doesn't work with me. I'll try it with Selenium and see

Comment: It worked with Selenium. However, would be neat if it could return the values in dicts like this `{'date': 'Apr 19 2015", 'Viewers': 100023, 'Channels': 82312}`. I don't understand the outputted numbers lists and the corresponding dates.